# Unique value in row compared to previous rows by group and year in dataframe

Tags: r

I am working with patent data and I would like to find out whether firms have been assigned patents in similar or dissimilar patent classes in the years prior to the year the current patent has been assigned.

As an example: Firm 1010 (see table below) has patented in subcat 67 in year 1984 and I would like to find out whether it has applied for a patent in the same subcat in the X previous years (where X could be 3 or 5, for example). The result should be that for every patent (row), a value of 1 gets assigned if this is the case and 0 if not.

The amount of observations per firm (gvkey) and publication year are unbalanced (so not the same amount of observations for every firm).

I have fumbled around with `dplyr` and `data.table`, but cannot seem to find any solution that comes even close.

```
    gvkey publn_year subcat  patent
 1:  1010       1980     53 4184663
 2:  1010       1980     55 4185564
 3:  1010       1980     53 4187814
 4:  1010       1981     45 4242866
 5:  1010       1981     55 4242966
 6:  1010       1981     69 4246928
 7:  1010       1982     53 4310145
 8:  1010       1982     53 4311298
 9:  1010       1982     69 4313458
10:  1010       1983     69 4367764
11:  1010       1983     53 4368927
12:  1010       1983     53 4368928
13:  1010       1984     67 4428585
14:  1010       1984     53 4429855
15:  1010       1984     53 4430983
16:  1012       1987     52 4683010
17:  1013       1980     43 4203066
18:  1013       1981     41 4245879
19:  1013       1982     41 4363941
20:  1013       1983     41 4367907
```

I've searched here and elsewhere for help but have not found what I'm looking for. I'm sure this is possible and I may be overlooking something very simple.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution *for the whole past* is as follows

```
df %>% 
     group_by(gvkey, subcat) %>% 
           mutate(flagged = ifelse(min(publn_year) == publn_year, 
                                       0, 
                                       1)
                  )
```

**Example**

Consider the data

```
> df
  gvkey publn_year subcat patent
1  1010       1979     53  44434
2  1010       1980     55  43424
3  1010       1981     53 243423
4  1010       1982     45 234234
```

Then you get

```
> df %>% group_by(gvkey, subcat) %>% mutate(flagged = ifelse(min(publn_year) == publn_year, 0, 1))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   gvkey, subcat [3]
  gvkey publn_year subcat patent flagged
  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1  1010       1979     53  44434       0
2  1010       1980     55  43424       0
3  1010       1981     53 243423       1
4  1010       1982     45 234234       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `dplyr`. First, `group_by` both `gvkey` for firm and `subcat` for subcategory. Then, `arrange` and sort by year. Then, you can add a column with your new value of 0/1 based on if the difference between a year and the most recent year of patent were within X years (here example is 3 years). I also check to see if the first row within a group, so that does not get set as 1. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gvkey, subcat) %>%
  arrange(gvkey, subcat, publn_year) %>%
  mutate(prior = ifelse(publn_year - lag(publn_year) <= 3 & row_number() != 1, 1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
   gvkey publn_year subcat  patent prior
   <int>      <int>  <int>   <int> <dbl>
 1  1010       1981     45 4242866     0
 2  1010       1980     53 4184663     0
 3  1010       1980     53 4187814     1
 4  1010       1982     53 4310145     1
 5  1010       1982     53 4311298     1
 6  1010       1983     53 4368927     1
 7  1010       1983     53 4368928     1
 8  1010       1984     53 4429855     1
 9  1010       1984     53 4430983     1
10  1010       1980     55 4185564     0
11  1010       1981     55 4242966     1
12  1010       1984     67 4428585     0
13  1010       1981     69 4246928     0
14  1010       1982     69 4313458     1
15  1010       1983     69 4367764     1
16  1012       1987     52 4683010     0
17  1013       1981     41 4245879     0
18  1013       1982     41 4363941     1
19  1013       1983     41 4367907     1
20  1013       1980     43 4203066     0
```

Comment: Hi Ben, this is exactly what I was looking for. I now also see why I kept bugging around (should have grouped by subcat, not publn_year). Thank you so much!